# Name manager: choosing a Range with a formula

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula

I've been receiving an error when I try to set the range as so:

```
=EMPLOYEE_list!$D$2:ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/(EMPLOYEE_list!D:D<>""),ROW(EMPLOYEE_list!D:D)),4,4)
```

The second part looks for the address of the last non-empty cell in that column and outputs the relative value of the address.

The purpose of this is to take a list of names find the address of the last non-empty cell and use that to determine the range for this list.

example:
I have 5 names from cells D2 to D6.
the address formula returns D6 to be the last row and the range should read D2:D6

Sorry if my explanation is confusing I'm trying to provide as much info as possible.

Comment: What is your question? What error are you getting? Does this have something to do with VBA? It looks like just a formula.

Comment: i'm using the name manager to define a group of employee names to be used in a drop down menu.  The list is dynamic as there are often new employees and so i use a sort function to make sure there are no blank spaces between names and then have a function to find the last occupied cell and output the relative address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to build a range reference like that, you need to return a reference rather than a string.

Try this

```
=EMPLOYEE_list!$D$2:INDEX(EMPLOYEE_list!D:D,LOOKUP(2,1/(EMPLOYEE_list!D:D<>""),ROW(EMPLOYEE_list!D:D)))
```

This will return a reference to `D2:D6` as per your example.

Comment: Thanks this solved everything nicely.  I was wondering if you could explain how you came to this formula using index and such. I'm not that familiar with vba and excel.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no gaps you can use OFFSET for a dynamic named range, i.e. something like this

`=OFFSET(EMPLOYEE_list!$D$2,0,0,COUNTA(EMPLOYEE_list!$D$2:$D$1000))`

If you might have gaps try:

`=EMPLOYEE_list!$D$2:INDEX(EMPLOYEE_list!D:D,MATCH("zzz",EMPLOYEE_list!D:D))`

Comment: i'm circumventing the gaps by running a sort function before hand for formatting and readability to the end users.